# simple SQL request problem

Tags: php, sql, html, database, join

I have two tables.

location which contains the lat,lon and id of some city

poi which contains a list of poi with a unique id

I'm trying to select all the POI inside a radius

```
SELECT location.id, longitude, latitude (6371 * acos(cos(radians(46.4166268823293)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-1.5623357632014)) + sin(radians(46.4166268823293)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM location,poi 
WHERE poi.id = location.id
HAVING distance < 20
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

So i select all the location that are inside my 20km radius. the id of the location is linked to the unique id of the PO table so that's why i'm trying to join the two table

But the join doesn't seem to work. Whe ni try this request on phpMyAdmin it shows only the id,longitute and latitue but it doesn't show field of the POI table (which im intersted in ..)

May somebody can help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't select any field of poi. Try `SELECT ... poi.* FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

These are the only fields in your select clause. If you do

```
SELECT POI.*,location.id, longitude, latitude
```

You would see more

Answer (score 0):

But you do not select a field from `POI`, how do you expect this field to be in the result set ?

```
Select location.id, POI.Field-from-POI, longitude, latitude ...
```